# how to display address in google map

Tags: c#, jquery, vb.net, google-maps, jquery-plugins

I am displaying google map on my asp.net page using jquery.I have Nation name,company name,Address and Longitude and latitude.

Right now i have add all addresses in dropdown,on the basis of dropdown selection i  have passed longitude and latitude in code.this part is working as it display map on the basis of latitude and longitude.But i have no longitude and latitude for some comapnies.So i want to use directly address of comapnies to display map.

Here is the code that i have used:

```
  <script src="js/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <msdropdown> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/msdropdown/dd.css" />
    <script src="js/msdropdown/jquery.dd.js"></script>



    <link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC6v5-2uaq_wusHDktM9ILcqIrlPtnZgEk&sensor=false">
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places">
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="initialize()">
    <select  id="countries" style="width:300px;" onchange="updateMap(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
          <option value='TVSH - Rruga Ismail Quemali 11>TVSH - Rruga Ismail Quemali 11, Tirana</option></select>


  function updateMap(selectControl) {
            alert(selectControl);
            switch (selectControl) {
                case 'TVSH - Rruga Ismail Quemali 11, Tirana':
                    var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
                        path: [

  new google.maps.LatLng(41.321102, 19.823112)],
                        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                        strokeWeight: 2
                    });

                    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.321102, 19.823112)
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
            initialize(polyline, latLng);
        }

        function initialize(polyline, schoolLatLng) {
            var myLatLng = schoolLatLng;
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 13,
                center: myLatLng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
            };


            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

            polyline.setMap(map);

        }
```

Now map is displaying on the basis of latitude and longitude.Is there any way so i can directly show map on the basis address.I have address of all comapnies like this:**EURONEWS - 60, chemin des Mouilles - 69130 Lyon-Écully, France**

Can i show map on the base of this address.Please ask me more description if you need.

Comment: You can include the geocoder which gives you back the latitude and longitude.

Comment: @putvande thanks,can you point me any example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/), the API purpose is exactly the transformation of an adress into coordinates, then with this coordinates you can render the map, as you already did.

Example:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
//convert location into longitude and latitude
geocoder.geocode({
    address: 'chemin des Mouilles - 69130 Lyon-Écully, France'
}, function(locResult) {
    var lat1 = locResult[0].geometry.location.lat();
    var lng1 = locResult[0].geometry.location.lng();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': 'chemin des Mouilles - 69130 Lyon-Écully, France'}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
    });
  } else {
    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
  }
});
```

But watch out cause the geocoder is asynchronous.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding

Answer (score 0):

Or you could check these 2 services for alternatives. I have most of the data printing out that they send back to you, just hit the find me button. But pull your console up to see it all.

[Codepen.io Example](http://codepen.io/calebnance/pen/lxoyt)